For which $n$ is the bipartite graph $F_n = K_{n,n} -nK_2$ planar?
Problem:
Let $F_n = K_{n,n} -nK_2$ be the bipartite graph wich we optain from $K_{n,n}$ by deleting $n$ independent edges (that is, no two of these n edges have a common endpoint). For which n is $F_n$ planar?
Idea:
First of all, this is relatively obvious for $n≤3$.
I know that $F_n​$ is planar if and only if it has an abstract dual $H$. The definition of an abstract dual is that there must exist a bijective function $ϕ:E(F_n)→E(H)$ that maps cycles to bonds and vice versa. My idea was to show that such a mapping cannot exist for, say, $n=5
$, but I’m not really getting anywhere with it. I would appreciate a tip :)

Why not use the definition of being planar? It is a lot easier to actually draw a diagram of $K_{4,4} - 4K_2$ without crossings than it is to try to construct an abstract dual out of thin air.

$F_n$ has $2n$ vertices and $n^2-n$ edges, and is bipartite.
A bipartite planar graph with $2n$ vertices can contain at most $2(2n)-4$ edges, and the condition $n^2-n \le 4n-4$ is true only when $1 \le n \le 4$. So $F_5$ and onwards cannot be planar. (We can also prove this by finding a subdivision of $K_5$ inside $F_5$, but that's harder.)
We can check that $F_1$ through $F_4$ are all planar by drawing them. The only tricky case is $F_4$, and a shortcut is to observe that $F_4$

 is isomorphic to the cube graph.


It’s easier to see that $K_{3,3}$ is a subgraph of $F_n$ for $n>5$.

@Pranay Yes, but that does not address the case of $F_5$.

Here is an illustration with a planar drawing of $F_4$ and a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ inside $F_5$.
